# targeting the element from where event is generated

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I have a custom event trigger on adding an item to a shopping cart:

```
var order = function (){
   $(document).trigger('customEvent');
    ...........
   ........
};
```

I have a structure where price of the item is listed and when adding that item in cart I have to grab the price from dom . The issue is if I listen to customEvent, it will target the document instead of where event is triggered.

Is there a way to target that element?

These all point to document not the element.

```
event.target || event.srcElement || event.originalTarget || $(event.target)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `$(this)` inside the event handler? AFAIK, it should point to the actual element that received the event.

```
$('#myElement').on('customEvent',function(){
  $(this).text('foo')
})
$('#mySecondElement').on('customEvent',function(){
  $(this).text('bar')
})
$(document).trigger('customEvent')
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of triggering the event on the document element, why not trigger it on your item?

```
 $('#itemThatWasAddedId').trigger('customEvent');
```

..edit from comments..

If all you need to do retrieve some information relative to div that is clicked, instead of using the document customEvent handler thats attached to your page, you can just use the simple $().click() event.

```
$('#itemThatWasAddedId').click(function(){ 
    //retrieve the item price using the inner html, or a selector..
    $(this).html();
})
```

Comment: correct, a global event doesn't make any sense in this context ^^

Comment: well it is a common functionality used across different pages ...and I  cannot touch that function since developed by some other team ...I was thinking about creating a custom click trigger using $.Event constructor ...that way i can capture that event and target the element...

Comment: well why go through all that work, if its going to be a click event anyways, you can just use $().click() , I'll edit my answer